# docker push doesn't use the correct repository and fails

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I'm trying to push a docker image to an Azure container repository and even after successfully "logging in" the push command tries to push it to docker.io and then fails.

> Note: I am using Windows 10 Pro and have set up docker to to use the [minikube](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-minikube/) docker dameon

How do I tell `docker push` to use my Azure container repo?

See the output:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must tag your image with the Docker Registry URL and then push like this:

```
docker tag design-service dockerregistry.azurecr.io/design-service
docker push dockerregistry.azurecr.io/design-service
```

Note: The correct term is *registry* and not *repository*.  A Docker registry holds repositories of tagged images.